# Does the global maximum and minimum refer to a turning point of a graph or the highest/lowest value obtained in an interval of the graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

So if for example I had a function like the following $f(x) = x^4-2x^2$ in the interval $[\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{4}{3}]$. In order to find the global maxima or minima I'd take the derivative with respect to x giving $f'(x) = 4x^3 - 4x$. Then find the values at which this derivative is $0$. So my question is, for this example would 0 be the global maximum?

What if I changed the domain to $(0,1]$ for example. Would this global maximum no longer exist since it's not within the domain or would it?

& one final question if you amended the domain from the original part to $[\frac{-1}{3}, 2]$ would 0 still remain as the global maximum or would the new global maximum be at x=2 even though this isn't a region where there's a turning point? Thank you.

Comment: Global extremum depends upon the interval. Also a constant function has no "turning point" but every point is global extremum.

Comment: Your $f'(x)=4x^3\color\red{-}4x$.

Comment: The derivative is $0$ at local minima and maxima.  To find global minima and maxima you also have to check the endpoints, and any points where the derivative doesn't exist.